# Synonym for to make a pilgrimage?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word for the act of making a pilgrimage?

> The text excludes the following people from the requirement to make a pilgrimage....

Answer (score 13):

## *pilgrim* = *peregrine*

Though Chaucer famously had his springtide folk “long to go on pilgrimages, and palmers to seek strange strands”, our common word *pilgrim* ultimately derives from Latin *peregrīnus*.

This same etymon has historically supplied us with a host of other, closely related terms which though less common today than they were of old, are still sometimes used — especially if you know some Romance or history.

So for example:

- A pilgrim is a *peregrine*. (in English since the year 1395)
- To go on a pilgrimage is to *to peregrinate*. (since 1593)
- A pilgrimage is the same thing as a *peregrination* (since 1475) or the older and now-obsolete *peregrinage*. (since 1340)
- If you worry that your peregrines might be confused for raptors, try the newer *peregrinator* instead. (since 1610)
- Although *peregrinity* (since 1591) once meant a foreign journey, it now means foreignness if it means anything at all. It may be obsolete.
- *Peregrinancy* (since 1674) once meant restlessness or inclination toward movement, but it too is now obsolete.

A recent OED citation for the verb *peregrinate* in the sense of “travels broadly” is used in a figurative sense:

> - 1996   Voice Lit. Suppl. (Nexis) 9 July 12
>   He..peregrinates widely across cultural criticism and history to put Atlanta in context.

However, these are all fancy, learnèd terms, and you wouldn’t want to just plunk them down in any old bit of text.

Once you realize that *pilgrim = peregrine*, all else follows.

Comment: Great answer. Why did you use a grave accent above the last 'e' in learned? Do you do the same for "blessed" and "cursed" when they're pronounced as two syllables? Is there a style guide that recommends this or were you taught to do this?

Answer (score 5):

The verb is the same as the noun, so if you go on a pilgrimage you are pilgrimaging.

See [this entry at ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pilgrimage).

So your sentence would be:

> The text excludes the following people from the requirement to pilgrimage.

Comment: This is technically correct, but not necessarily a good recommendation in practice.  In mainstream English, this verb usage is pretty unusual, and so the suggested phrasing will look like a grammar error to many readers.  Unless the readers of the text are from some community or subculture where *pilgrimage* is more commonly used as a verb, the original phrasing *…the requirement to make a pilgrimage…* will be more widely and easily understood.

Comment: Really? It was the first thing I thought of, and I'm pretty sure is generally accepted English.

Answer (score 4):

**The answer lies in your question.**

Apart from using [pilgrimage](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pilgrimage) as a noun, you can also use it as a verb in accordance with the following definition:

> 1. go on a pilgrimage

Usage examples:

> 1. He **pilgrimaged** last year with his mother.
> 2. Every year, Muslims **pilgrimage** with immense amount of religious passion.